# encrypting parameters of a querystring via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I want to redirect to some page with querystring,and the querystring value should be in encrypted format and i want to decrypt that in codebehind

**example:**

`function redirect(s, e) { window.location.href = "Default2.aspx?Id=" + encrypt(5)+ "&No=" +encrypt( 5);}`

and in codebehind:

```
Dim id As String = Request.QueryString("Id").ToString()
        id = Decode(id)
Dim no As String = Request.QueryString("No").ToString()
        no= Decode(no)
```

Thanks in Advance

Arasu Rajendran

Comment: That won't be secure. Since your encryption algorithm is public (it's in the JavaScript source of your page) and the range of values is quite small (numeric ID), decrypting the contents is a trivial exercise for any hacker.

Comment: how about ? http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+encryption  (of cource can not be 100% secure...

Comment: What is the purpose of encrypting the data? If you want to protect it in transit then use SSL.

Comment: In your code example, you're using the word "decode".  Are you wanting to Encode/Decode or Encrypt/Decrypt?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encrypt the query string server-side before sending it to the client, then decrypt it server-side.

Have a look at this question.  [Encrypt and decrypt a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net)